# Как узнать столько timestamp было в ровное время

Tags: javascript

```js
let time = new Date().getTime();
console.log(time); // 1617602830059
```

К примеру сейчас 08:48:46 и надо узнать сколько timestamp было в:

```
08:48:00 // 1 мин
08:45:00 // 15 мин
08:30:00 // 30 мин
08:00:00 // 1 час
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, достаточно было взять остаток от деления на интервал

```js
let time = new Date().getTime();

let interval = [
  60, // 1m
  300, // 5m
  900, // 15m
  1800, // 30m
  3600, // 1h
];

function dateFloor(time, int){
  return new Date(time - (time % (int * 1000)));
}

console.log( dateFloor(time, interval[0]).getTime() );
console.log( dateFloor(time, interval[1]).getTime() );
console.log( dateFloor(time, interval[2]).getTime() );
console.log( dateFloor(time, interval[3]).getTime() );
console.log( dateFloor(time, interval[4]).getTime() );
```